# Привязка функции, написанной на Си, к pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, c, pandas

Возникла необходимость привязать функцию написанную на Си, к pandas.DataFrame или pandas.Series.
Прошу подсказки как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования С-кода в python наиболее удобно оформить его в вид, который импортит `ctypes` (чаще всего помещают просто функции), а далее просто цепляете в python-коде и пользуетесь - натравливаете на "датафрейм" или что вы собирались сделать.

```py
import ctypes

c_lib = ctypes.CDLL("./my_func_on_c.so")

my_result = c_lib.my_function()
```